# javascript load events not working with multiple IDs

Tags: javascript, load

how to load comments using  load event function for multiple ids

**html code**

```
          <div id="user2<?php echo $d['qid'];>">
          comments code
         </div>
```

**JS CODE**

```
  setInterval(function(){

            $("#user2").load('test2.php #user2'+qid).fadeIn(1000);

      },1000);
```

please help me  I  have tried many times not working

Comment: What are you asking? What does your HTML look like? Are you getting errors? This question doesn't have enough information for users to help you.

Comment: @luxdvie  Whats you problem  Id="qid"  and <div id ="user2 <?php echo ['qid']"?> Conment code</div>

Comment: Update your answer to include the HTML. Based on your question it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Be a little more descriptive and someone can probably lead you in the right direction.

Comment: @luxdvie see my updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="user21">
      <!-- HTML -->
</div>
<div id="user22">
      <!-- HTML -->
</div>
<div id="user23">
      <!-- HTML -->
</div>
```

You could load like this:

```
for (i = 1; i < 4 i++) { 
  $("#user2"+i).load("test2.php").fadeIn(1000);
}
```